# BotFramework message from web client was lost a text

Tags: botframework

When I send a text "!" from Skype web client

I have receive correct text "!"

[image]

But when I send a text "!!" from Skype web client

I have receive incorrect text ""

[image]

From desktop Skype are always correct

**More details**

"web client message" -> "bot activity.text"

1. "!" -> "!"
2. "!!" -> ""
3. "!!!" -> "!"
4. "!!!!" -> "!!"

[image]

[image]

I think problem in the Web Skype, because showed a empty outcome message

[image]

**Question:** *What cause is?*

Comment: It looks like a bug in the processing of the messages by the bot connector or even on Skype side. As you can see the format of the Channel Data is really different

Comment: @NicolasR thanks, i think it is bug of web skype. i have added more screenoshots